# Html and javascript extrating Id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble understanding how to use javascript and html together. I have managed to access the file ok and get id's from the file. But I can only access an id when the id's defined before the id I want has been used. Is there a way to get around this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="JavaS.js" async></script>

<title>This is my website</title>

</head>

<body>

<header align="center" id="head01"></header>

<p id="HouseName01"></p>

<p id="HouseAdress03"></p>

<footer id="foot01" align="center"></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML = "&copy;  " + new Date().getFullYear() + " Dane. All rights reserved.";
document.getElementById("head01").innerHTML = "Dane & Co";

document.getElementById("HouseName01").innerHTML = "House 1 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAdress01").innerHTML = "House 1 adress";
document.getElementById("HouseImage01").setAttribute("src", "C:/Users/currys/Pictures/House01.jpg");

document.getElementById("HouseName02").innerHTML = "House 2 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAdress02").innerHTML = "House 2 adress";

document.getElementById("HouseName03").innerHTML = "House 3 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAdress03").innerHTML = "House 3 adress";

document.getElementById("HouseName04").innerHTML = "House 4 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAdress04").innerHTML = "House 4 adress";

document.getElementById("HouseName05").innerHTML = "House 5 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAdress05").innerHTML = "House 5 adress";

document.getElementById("HouseName06").innerHTML = "House 6 name";
document.getElementById("HouseAdress06").innerHTML = "House 6 adress";

document.getElementById("tempVar").innerHTML = "House22";
```

Here is my javascript code. Sorry for not adding the code first time.

Comment: Nobody can help without showing some code and a more detailed problem description that relates to that specific code along with explanation of what you expect the code to do.

Comment: Those of us on the internet unfortunately (or fortunately!) don't have divining powers that allow us to see what it is you're talking about without more information.

Comment: if I understand you right, putting the script tag at the bottom of the body (under the footer) will do the trick. The DOM needs to be created before you can access it. If I don't understand you right, you may have to try again telling what you mean exactly ;)

Comment: Use var a= document.all; it'll return all the elements of your document and will store it in array named "a" here .

Comment: It's not that as the script has the async inside the script tag. I am also able to all the id "HouseName01", "foot01" and "head01" but cannot call the id "HouseAdress03".

Comment: just give it a try: async doesn't mean the dom is first created, but that the js and html are both loaded at the same time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the HTML element whose id is `"tempVar"` before to be defined, You can not do that:

```
`document.getElementById(<id>)` method is to get existing element identified by its id.
```

If you want to create a HTML element using js:

```
var newElement = document.createElement("p"); //i.e. <p></p>
var node = document.createTextNode("House22");
newElement.appendChild(node);
```

And later you can add this element `newElement`  inside the DOM.